# CSS line-height property issue

Tags: html, css

I incorporated a Material-Floating Button to my web page and the functionality is working perfectly the way I want it to. The only issue I am having is the icons I have set up for them are not appear centered but, appears at the top of the button. It appears that the css line-height is not working.

Image of what appears on my webpage: [Icon at top of Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSzMt.png)

Link for Material-Floating Button: [Material-Floating Button](https://github.com/nobitagit/material-floating-button#toggling-opts)

Link for Demo of where the icon should be at: [Demo](http://nobitagit.github.io/material-floating-button/)

HTML Code:

```
<ul class="mfb-component--br mfb-zoomin" data-mfb-toggle="hover">
  <li class="mfb-component__wrap">
      <!-- the main menu button -->
      <a href="#" class="mfb-component__button--main">
        <!-- the main button icon visible by default -->
        <i class="mfb-component__main-icon--resting ion-plus-round"></i>
        <!-- the main button icon visible when the user is hovering/interacting with the menu -->
        <i class="mfb-component__main-icon--active ion-close-round"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="mfb-component__list">
        <!-- a child button, repeat as many times as needed -->
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-mfb-label="Edit This Action" class="mfb-component__button--child">
            <i class="mfb-component__child-icon ion-edit"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Part of CSS Code:

```
.mfb-component__button--main, .mfb-component__button--child {
  background-color: #E40A5D;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-user-drag: none;
  color: #f1f1f1; }

/**
 * This is the unordered list for the list items that contain
 * the child buttons.
 *
 */
.mfb-component__list {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; }
  .mfb-component__list > li {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 1px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin: -10px 0; }

/**
 * These are the basic styles for all the icons inside the main button
 */
.mfb-component__icon, .mfb-component__main-icon--active,
.mfb-component__main-icon--resting, .mfb-component__child-icon {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 56px;
  width: 100%; }

.mfb-component__wrap {
  padding: 25px;
  margin: -25px; }
```

Comment: Removed it and the circle containing the icon just disappears

Comment: when changing to block the circle containing the icon remains but the icon still appears at the top

Comment: the `top:0px;` in mfb-component__list, this maybe effecting the position of the plus icon

Comment: unfortunately no the top:0px; was not effecting the position of the plus icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're right about the line-height. Is there another css rule somewhere over-riding it?
Try adding and important to target it a bit better.

```
line-height: 56px !important;
```

If that doesn't work add some parent elements before you're css rule like #menu and .mfb-component__wrap

```
#menu .mfb-component__wrap i.mfb-component__main-icon--active.ion-close-round{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 56px;
  width: 100%; }
```

If neither of the above work just use 'top' as a workaround instead.

```
#menu .mfb-component__wrap i.mfb-component__main-icon--active.ion-close-round{
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 17px; }
```

Hope that sorts it for you!

Comment: Yeah I have tried both but for some reason the line-height is not even being implemented. It looks like its ignoring line-height because on the demo and you inspect the element and you deselect line-height, the icon relocates to the top of the button. I will have to look through other css files to see if it could be overwriting it

Comment: Are you using the inspector tools in your browser to mess with the css. You shouldn't have to go looking through other css files to find the problem. You can just play around with it in the browser until you get it right and then update the relevant files. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-styles

Comment: @FiDown just use top:17px; and line-height: 0; instead so. That should do as a workaround. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you!!! I was playing with the css like you said using the inspector tools in the browser and found what was causing the issue. Didn't realize it was using     line-height:1 from ionicons.css and not the line-height from mfb.css. So i changed the line-height in ionicons.css and now the icons are centered.